# Azure Pipeline Run shell commands on remote machine via SSH Copy from Artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I m trying to copy my artifacts on my dedicated ubuntu server via the azure pipeline.

when i am using the "Copy Files over SSH" task i always get the error

"Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: All configured authentication methods failed"

When i am using the same SSH Connection with the "SSH - Run shell commands on remote machine" task the connection works and i can connect to my server and execute commands.

So my question is, is it possible to run the ssh command and copy from the pipeline artifacts to my server ?

my code to try the copy task:

```
echo 'i am connected'
echo '--------Start to copy --------'
sudo cp $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Lobi.Web/drop /root/test -r
echo '--------Copy END--------'
```

which results in the error

cp: cannot stat 'D:ar1a/_Lobi.Web/drop': No such file or directory

Comment: When you use "SSH" task, the commands are run on your remote machine. But "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Lobi.Web/drop" is the path of your artifact on your pipeline agent. The path on the pipeline agent cannot be found on the remote machine, so you get the error “No such file or directory‘. Based on the current situation, there is no problem with SSH Connection itself. To narrow down the issue, it's suggested that you create a new Ubuntu VM with the newer version and check whether "Copy Files over SSH" task works or not. Tested on ubuntu 20.04, it works fine.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT ah sorry, there are important things missing. 
i m using a Ubuntu 22.04 server. Whats confusing me is that i can connect with the same SSH Connection using the Copy Files Task with the normal SSH, but not with the copy files over ssh - task

Comment: It seems that "Copy Files over SSH" task and "SSH" task work differently. In order to find out whether this issue is related to your server environment, you can create a new ubuntu VM and test if "Copy Files over SSH" task works on it. As a workaround, if you are using Azure VM, you can use task [Azure File Copy](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV1/README.md) to copy files to the VM directly. If not, you can use this task and copy to the Storage Account firstly and then copy to your server.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a service connection to connect to your ubuntu server in azure devops portal, record the **connection name** as the **sshEndpoint** in task.
   [image]
2. coding a sample:

   ```
    trigger: none

    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Run Script --- write txt file
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          "Hello world" | out-file "test.txt"

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Run Script --- check file in DefaultWorkingDirectory
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          Get-ChildItem -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -Include test.txt

    - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: myUbuntu
        sourceFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        contents: 'test.txt' # string. Required. Contents. Default: **.
        targetFolder: '/home/azureuser'
        readyTimeout: '20000' # string. Required. SSH handshake timeout. Default: 20000.
   ```
3. my result, test.txt file already copied to remote:

   [image]
4. attention to the permissio of folders, it may encounter a **"Permission denied Local"** error, use **chmod** command to resolve this.

Comment: I will try that later and accept your answer if it works, thanks!

Comment: ah i misread it completly. i already tried that and i got the error message in my question when i am using the copyFilesOverSSH - Task :/